# Toggle off grid lines in Excel using JXL

Tags: java, toggle, jxl, gridlines

This is my code for toggle off grid lines while create new Excel file using JXL. But this return false. Help me on this. Am struggling with it

```
File exlFile = new File(sOutputDirectory + "/" + sOutputFileName+".xls");
            WritableWorkbook writableWorkbook = Workbook
                    .createWorkbook(exlFile);
            WritableSheet writableSheet = writableWorkbook.createSheet(
                    "Sheet1", 0);
            writableSheet.getSettings().setPrintGridLines(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
  writableSheet.getSettings().setShowGridLines(false);
```

It worked for me.